# git revert remove commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log, git-revert

I am interested in reverting a *pushed* commit but also removing it from the graph.
E.g. I have:

```
                   tag
A <— B <— C <— D <— E  <— F  
                          HEAD
```

I would like to remove `F` completely so my graph looks like:

```
                   tag
A <— B <— C <— D <— E  
                   HEAD
```

How can I do this?

Comment: git reset --hard HEAD~1

Comment: Just for the record, this action is a history-rewriting action. So if you already pushed the commit and others pulled it and you now push --force the commit(what you definitly have to do) you will destroy the remote history.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong to try to rewrite history.

People who cloned/pulled it will have hard time integrating your change, and may eventually push back the changes you wished to remove.

It's better to revert a commit, which will append a "negative" commit to your history.

```
git revert F
```

And the just push it

```
git push origin master
```

---

In case you know what you're doing or don't care about breaking everything, you can rewrite history:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Moves the index back to the parent commit (E)

```
git push --force
```

Pushes the new branch reference to the remote repository, regardless if it is fast-forward or not.